# What are some of the miracles asscoiated with Sripad Madhvacharya?

Tags: madhvacharya

Madhvacharya, one of the most renowned Vaishnava acharyas and the propagator of the Dvaita Vedanta philosophy, is considered an incarnation of Vayu by his followers. I would like to know some of the miracles supposedly performed by him?

Edit: As User @[Rickross](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/4732/rickross) suggested, I am willing to accept a minimum of two ''miracles'' as an answer.

Comment: The question is too broad. It should be more specific relating to a particular miracle claimed and then the last sentence may be claimed as a supplementary question.

Comment: You can say in the Q that u will accept the answer which gives at least two such miracles..even one will be sufficient.. in that way ur Q can be reopened.. if u decide to edit like the way i suggested then ping me here. @@surya

Comment: @Rickross The question has been edited the way you suggested.

Comment: Okay i have  cast my reopen vote..@SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury

Comment: 'too broad' is a poor reason to close your recent Q's concerning miracles performed by acharyas. 'too broad' applies to gods like Indra, Shiva, Vishnu etc. where they performed 100's of miracles. It's silly to apply that reason to acharyas. Your original post is good as such, no edit was necessary. I voted to re-open before the edit. We have a lot of noob users wasting other users' time in the process of closing/re-opening Q's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is considered as mukhya prANa by followers. He was an influential figure in vaishnava tradition as well as vedanta. There are several miracles associated with him and his disciples.

Some of the miracles are mentioned below

> As a child he had performed a lot of miracles, which foretold his
> future greatness. Once he was asked to protect the curds and milk kept
> in the pots from cats. Being playful and restive child, he lifted two
> huge pieces of granites and closed the milk and curd pots. These
> mosuru kallu (curd stone) and Halu kallu (milk stone) has been
> preserved for the posterity, even today at Pajaka shetra.
>
> Madhyageha bhataa (father of Vasudeva), once took loan from a local
> money lender for purchasing cows. He was not able to pay back the
> debts and the money lender was pressurizing him. On knowing this
> Vasudeva(Madhwa) gave a handful of tamarind seeds to the money lender
> and said that father’s loan has been settled. To the money lender’s
> surprise, the tamarind seeds given by Vasudeva was turned in gold
> nuggets and money lender was happy to receive the loan had paid back.
>
> One day when he was teaching Ithreya Upanishad to his pupils, he
> suddenly disappeared in a Pushpa vrishti (shower of flowers). That day
> is celebrated every year as Madhwa navami during magha shukla paksha.
> It is believed; even today he is staying at upper Badari and listening
> to Sri Vedavyasa’s teaching.

[Source](http://atlantarayaramath.org/Saints/Madhwacharya)

Comment: missed many importan miracle bhemmana bhand 1 ton stone lifted by madhva and placed removing hindrance to flow of river. Was in badri spoke to vyasa personally got the blessing to write brahma sutra bhasya from Lord VedaVyasa himself.. Source madhva Vijaya